# How to make sure endpoint doesn't execute a method if it's already running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have an endpoint which runs a method. I want to ensure that method will not be executed while it's running when I hit the endpoint multiple times.

I imagine I can set a variable somewhere in the thread pool or something? I'm not sure how to go about investigating this.Some leads would be appreciated.

My example:

```
namespace Website.Import
{
    public class ImportProducts : IHttpHandler
    {
        private static bool running = false;
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            if (running)
            {
                throw new Exception("Already running");
            }

            running = true;

            try
            {
                var repo = new MemoryRepository();

                var productImporter = new ProductImporter(repo);
                var groupImporter = new GroupImporter(repo);
                var discountImporter = new DiscountImporter(repo);
            }
            finally
            {
                running = false;
            }

            context.Response.Write("Done");

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen to the other requests? Should they return errors? Wait for completion and then take their own turn? Wait for completion and then share the result? Something else?

Comment: Returning a string message would be ideal, but honestly it doesn't matter in my case.

Comment: @EvaldasRaisutis you missed the comment's point. It *does* matter and what you ask is abusing HTTP's core behaviour and will definitelly lead to IIS problems. First, why do you assume that the requests will be served by the same *machine*? In a load balancing scenario that won't work

Comment: I know that the setup is running on a single server.

Comment: @EvaldasRaisutis if you want to execute a long running maintenance job for example, locking is the least of your problems as IIS doesn't like long-running requests. Use Hangfire to solve the issue. At least, store the job's status in some common storage (database, Redis cache, whatever) so that all servers know the state of the job

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lock object to ensure the action doesn't run in parallel.

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

lock (lockObject)
{
    // your code
}
```

There might be a problem though: this method will get locked for every user since static variables are shared across all sessions.

This behavior might be intentional. If you want to block execution for all sessions, this code is fine. If you want to block execution for only this user, allowing the method to run once at the same time per user, you have to put the object in the session storage.

If you just want to inform the client it is already running, you could also throw an exception:

```
private static bool alreadyExecuting = false;

if (alreadyExecuting)
{
    throw new Exception("Already running");
}

alreadyExecuting = true;

try
{
    // your code
}
finally
{
    alreadyExecuting = false;
}
```

Comment: Will this throw an error or will it wait for the lock to be done and then execute? I would prefer any subsequent endpoint hits to just return a string message, if they cannot run the method (due to it already running)

Comment: Is it the same case for .axhx handles?

Comment: Hm it doesn't seem to work. I've added my example to your response. If I run it once, and immediately again, it displays "done" on both tabs.

Comment: So they didn't collide. Try to put in a sleep for 10 seconds or so: `Thread.Sleep(10000)`.

Comment: Please stop editing my post to include your code. It distracts from my general purpose solution.

Comment: No that still doesn't work. I've tried toggling IsReusable but that has no effect.

Comment: Sorry, the `Thread.Sleep` was a bad idea since it blocks all sessions... That breaks your sample here.

Comment: I've added my example in my question.

Comment: @EvaldasRaisutis the very question is wrong. That's not how HTTP works. Have you considered load balancing for example? *Why* do you want to restrict the number of requests? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve and why do you think that blocking an endpoint is the solution? If you want to run a maintenance job, use Hangfire or some similar library to do it. At least, check the *job's* status, not the request's

Comment: I know the setup is run on a single server. I want to restrict requests, because the endpoint is responsible for Importing products to a webshop. Naturally, an import should not run more than once at a time.